# Observable QString in Qt

Tags: qt, observable, qstring

I would like changes to occur in my Qt application whenever a specific QString's value changes. I didn't find any reference to signals in `QString` documentation, so do I need to subclass `QString` and implement my own signals or are there preferred alternatives?

Comment: QString does not handle signals since it is a data container, perhaps a possible solution is to add create a class that inherits from QString and implement the signals.

Comment: Can't you handle that on whatever class changes the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't found any reference to signals, because that's not how you get notifications from data classes in Qt. What you need to do is use [the property system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html).

Simply implement the string as a `Q_PROPERTY` of some core logic object.

```
// in some QObject derived class
Q_PROPERTY(QString text MEMBER m_text NOTIFY textChanged)
QString m_text;
signals:
void textChanged();
// that's all you need
```

It would be a significant overhead to have a lot of strings, each of which inheriting `QObject`, as the [latter is rather big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763088/how-heavy-is-qobject-really). However, you can have a lot of strings implemented as a properties of a single object with close to no overhead.

If all you want to do is monitor a string for changes, then a property is all you need. A wrapper around `QString` is only justified if you need advanced functionality, notifications not only that the string has changed, but how has it changed, was it cleared, was a particular character replaced, was a bit of it cut or was there another string inserted and where. Kinda what you get for a data model.

Comment: Thanks, this seems indeed to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to define your own class with something like this :

```
class ObservableString : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(ObservableString)

public:
    void setValue(const QString &value) {
      
        if (m_string != value) {
            m_string = value;
            emit valueChanged(value);
        }
    }

    QString value() const {
        return m_string;
    }

signals:
    void valueChanged(QString value);

private:
    QString m_string;
};
```